# Stacked Widget Window Titlebar

Tags: qt, titlebar

I am creating a stacked widget, and want to have each widget have its own titlebar. I am adding the stacked widget to a preexisting layout. For some reason none of my stacked widgets have any sort of titlebar or window at all, just a blank space. I see many posts online on how to get rid of titlebars using setWindowFlags(), but not how to add one.

Answer (score 0):

The title bar is a feature that's only added to top-level widgets, also called windows, by the platform's window manager. It's not something that Qt adds or can make appear within a window itself.

You'll need to add the tile bar using a `QLabel` or a similar widget.